# Grouping documents in MongoDB and adding the document to an array

Tags: mongodb

**The Problem:**
I currently have a list of documents that I would like to group by the attribute 'eventType'. The document (representing a song) currently look like this:

```
Song Document:
{
    id: ID,
    eventType: String,
    numberOfLikes: Integer,
    sections: String[]
}
```

**Result:**
I would like to have these grouped by eventType, like as follows:

```
eventType: { 
    songs: [{
       songId: ID,
       numberOfLikes: Integer,
       sections: String[]
    }]
}
```

How would I do this using the MongoDB aggregation pipeline? I am using MongoDB 4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push root object in songs field using `$$ROOT`,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$eventType",
      songs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ipmTD_G0wUn)